# spring data jpa not working and class not found error

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have configured spring data jpa with my spring app

I am using Spring 3.2 and spring data jpa 1.1.0

Xml configuration

Repo class

```
public class TestRepo extends JpaRepository <Test, Long>{}
```

Error subclass PagingAndSortingRepository needed by JpaRepository cannot be found

I dont see any such class in the spring data jpa jar. Am I missing any jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included the spring-data-commons library

Comment: No, so that must be the problem. Let me check and come back to you

Comment: Yes that is it. I didnt think that is needed. I thought spring data jpa would be enough